# How I can cross my two different databases in two different server in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I execute query that return for me a fields of my first database in HTML table and one of this fields field "number" and i want to query another database using the same field  "number" to return a field "price" in my second database.

"number" it's the same filed in my two databases.

How can I do that in php ?

This my Code PHP :

```
   <?php  
                 if(isset($_POST['date']))
                 {

                    $pro_date = $_POST['date'];
                    $sql = "
                           SELECT 
                             left(list_product_order.number,8) as number,
                             list_product_order.created_at as date,
                             date(list_product_order.received) as received_date,
                             date(list_product_order.deliv) as deliv_date,
                             list_product_order.four_name as name,
                             COUNT(id_product_order) as items,
                             MONTH(list_product_order.created_at) as month,
                             -1 as price

                           FROM `list_product_order`

                           WHERE YEAR(list_product_order.created_at) = $date

                           GROUP BY list_product_order.number,month

                           ORDER BY list_product_order.created_at DESC 

                           ";

                           $datao->exec ( "set names utf8" );
                           $req = $datao->prepare($sql);
                           $req->execute();
                           $fquery = $req -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                }

                 $sqll = "
                         SELECT 
                         data_command.number as number,
                         data_command.sup_name as sup_name,
                         SUM(data_command_item.value * data_command_item.quantity) as price                                              

                         FROM data_command
                         LEFT JOIN data_command_item on data_command.id_number = data_command_item.fk_number
                         WHERE (data_command_item IN (implode(',',$fquery)))
                         ";

                   $datam->exec ( "set names utf8" );
                   $req = $datam->prepare($sqll);
                   $req->execute();
                   $squery = $req -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                         ?>

         <div class="panel-body">
             <?php if(isset($_POST['pro_date']))  
             { 

             foreach($fquery as $key => $value)
                      {
                         foreach($squery as $value2)
                         {
                             if($value['number'] === $value2['number'])
                             {
                                $fquery[$key]['four_name'] = $value2['sup_name'];
                                  $fquery[$key]['price'] = $value2['price'];

                             }               
                         }
                       }

                       echo '

                       <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover display" id="table_with_sorting" style="zoom: 85%">
                       <thead>
                       <tr>
                       <th style="font-size:11px">Number</th>
                       <th style="font-size:11px">Date</th>
                       <th style="font-size:11px">Name</th>
                       <th style="font-size:11px">Items</th>
                       <th style="font-size:11px">Received_date</th>
                       <th style="font-size:11px">Deliv_date</th>
                       <th style="font-size:11px">Month</th>
                       <th style="font-size:11px">Price</th>
                     </tr>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody>';
               <?php


                   foreach($fquery as $f)
                    {
                    echo "
                         <tr style='text-align: center;'>
                         <td>".$f['number']."</td>
                         <td>".$f['date']."</td>
                         <td>".$f['name']."</td>
                         <td>".$f['items']."</td>
                         <td>".$f['received_date']."</td>
                         <td>".$f['deliv_date']."</td>
                         <td>".$f['month']."</td>
                         <td>".$f['price']."</td>
                         </tr>";
                  }

                  echo" </tbody>
                   </table>";
                   ?>

                    <?php   }
                        ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <?php
                        ?>
                </div>
```

This my query for second database :

```
SELECT 

      data_command.number as number,
      data_command.sup_name as sup_name,
      SUM(data_command_item.value * data_command_item.quantity) as price                                              

FROM  data_command

LEFT JOIN data_command_item on data_command.id_number = data_command_item.fk_number
```

It display for me one number with -1 in price.

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you talking about different `database` or different `table`?

Comment: @D4V1D different databases :)

Comment: So how can two different databases have a **field** in common?

Comment: @D4V1D The same field i mean :)

Comment: I understood that. But databases do not store **fields**, they store **tables**. Can you be more precise please?

Comment: @D4V1D i have two different databases, field number it's the same field   in two databases i want te return price of my numbers and the price is in second database.

Comment: @ReaganGallant I can't use inner my databases they not in the same server.

Comment: @Sarah you right sorry . which storage engine is used?

Comment: @ReaganGallant innodb

Comment: Unfortunately you can't share a connection across multiple servers. you can however create multiple database instances to retrieve the relevant data and use it in code. @Erwin Moller got something going there.Otherwise check out federated storage engine.

Comment: @ReaganGallant i know it's possible with foreach in PHP but i don't know how

Comment: You can do this by using separate arrays,loops and merge that data based on specific positions but this will be messy and unmaintainable.

Comment: If it is feasible in your use-case you could use a daily dump of the contents of database2 imported in database1. If you only read and it is fine to have slightly outdated data.

Comment: I downvoted because it is unclear what you're asking (without reading the comments).

Comment: All that and it was unclear for u,if ur interested to help me u will ask me what 's unclear for u in my question but i think u love so much downvoted Thank u for ur answer.

Comment: @ReaganGallant Thank u for ur answers. What I want is to do it's the same thing what Erwin Mollet wrote in his comment foreach for two queries but it dosen't work :(

Comment: (Hi Sarah. A few tips for interacting here, perhaps they will be helpful? Firstly, we try to discourage folks from using Stack Overflow as a general chatroom - if comment threads get past 10 or so lines, perhaps the problem is too broad, and needs to be made more specific. Adding "here is my new code" in comments, whilst sometimes OK, might be better as an edit to the original question, so everyone can follow along - and in some cases it might be better as a new question entirely.)

Comment: (Also, if you encounter a minor problem with an answer, like an `Undefined variable`, then it is ideal if you can try fixing it yourself. Answers are best thought of as hints to help you find a solution, and not a verbatim text that will fix all your bugs. Lastly, please try to avoid chat-style speak such as "u" and "wen" - some English-speaking readers find it annoying, and it may be confusing for readers who do not have a strong command of English. Thanks!)

Comment: @halfer I use code and i fix my bugs myself, when i don't undestand something i ask for it. It's not always this answers here are correct to find the solution of my code.

Comment: @halfer Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using multiple database instances and load it data from that databases into separate arrays(See **$arrayOne** and **$arrayTwo** below).

Your result set will have a relationship(See the **"number"** field below) which you can use to append **$arrayTwo** values to **$arrayOne** using a nested foreach loop.

.You can then loop through **$arrayOne** and display it in a html Table.

NB!!
The following code:**(isset($items['sup_name']) ? $items['sup_name'] : 'No Supplier')**
Checks if a supplier exist, if not it will display "No Supplier".

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
//ArrayOne is the result from DB 1
$arrayOne = array(
    array("number" => 5, "date" => "12-01-2011", "name"=> "Jack","items" => 30),
    array("number" => 8, "date" => "12-05-2015", "name"=> "John","items" => 20),
    array("number" => 3, "date" => "12-08-2014", "name"=> "Sarah","items" => 320),
);
//Result from DB 2
$arrayTwo = array(
    array("number" => 3, "sup_name" => "Coke","price" =>"25000"),
    array("number" => 8, "sup_name" => "Simba","price" =>"1200"),
);
foreach($arrayOne as $key => $value){
    foreach($arrayTwo as $value2){
        if($value['number'] === $value2['number']){
            //add "sup_name" and "price" to arrayOne
            $arrayOne[$key]['sup_name'] = $value2['sup_name'];
            $arrayOne[$key]['price'] = $value2['price'];
        }               
    }
}
echo '
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover display" id="table_with_sorting" style="zoom: 85%"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
<th style="font-size:11px">Number</th> 
<th style="font-size:11px">Date</th> 
<th style="font-size:11px">Name</th> 
<th style="font-size:11px">Items</th> 
<th style="font-size:11px">Supplier Name</th> 
<th style="font-size:11px">Price</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> ';
foreach($arrayOne as $items)
{
    echo "<tr style='text-align: center;'><td>".$items['number']."</td> 
<td>".$items['date']."</td>
<td>".$items['name']."</td>
<td>".$items['items']." </td>
<td>". (isset($items['sup_name']) ? $items['sup_name'] : 'No Supplier')." </td>
<td>". (isset($items['price']) ? $items['price'] : '0.00')." </td></tr>";
}
echo '</tbody> 
</table> ';   
?>
```

**Result**

[image: Display data from different servers in html table]

**PHP Fiddle**
[Demo with source code in PHP fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/b8a7d41465733e55e1d3)

Comment: Thank u for ur answer. I have a file or it there's all the connections I call at the beginning of my page

Comment: Here is a link to loop throught associative array   http://www.journaldev.com/1528/php-arrays-indexed-associative-and-multidimensional-arrays

Comment: <?php
                   $firstRS = array();
                   foreach ($data_req as $one=>$p)
                   {
                 /*  $firstRS[$one["number"]] = $p;*/
                     echo "one=".$one." p=".$p;

                    }                                                                                       The result : one=0 p=Array one=1 ..... until the last number of my data :

Comment: <?php 
$firstRS = array(); 
foreach ($data_req as $one=>$p) 
{ 
 echo "one=".$one." p=".$p; 
 foreach ($array2 as $two=>$u) 
  {
   if($one == two)
      //do your thing
  }
}

Comment: @Sarah. I have updated my answer, Can you check out the example of the foreach loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84682/discussion-between-reagan-gallant-and-sarah).

Comment: what is id for u? okey wen continue in chat.

Comment: @halfer. I removed the backslashes. Thanks

Comment: @ReaganGallant i will test it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Undefined variable: arrayThree.

Comment: @Sarah sorry it should be $arrayOne not $arrayThree. I updated my answer.

Comment: @ don't worry I understand that this is the first array.

Comment: @ the price for me -1.

Comment: PHP notice will display if the price is empty. You can display an empty string or $0.00.

Comment: @Sarah I answered you question. I showed how to retrieve the data from the databases, Store it in multidimensional arrays. Join the data based on field value "Number" and ultimately display it in a html table but you still do not accept my answer.

Comment: @ I fix a lot of bugs in  my code but it works now, don't worry i accept your question it's best question for my problem. Thank you a lot Reagan for your answers.

Comment: Thanks again im glad too.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, the result from the first query return a column you named "number".

Now you want to query another database, using the numbers returned from the first query. Right?

When you use a database from the same vendor you can often join across databases. But you can also do it "by hand".

Just store the "number"s from the first query in an array, and use that array to query the second database, using something like:

```
$ArrMyNumbers = array();
// fill it with numbers from first resultset.
// pseudocode, I don't know your exact situation
foreach ($myFirstResultSet as $one){
  $ArrMyNumbers[] = (int)$one["number"];
}

And then for your second query:

$SQL2 = "SELECT data_command.number as number,
        data_command.sup_name as sup_name,
        SUM(data_command_item.value * data_command_item.quantity) as price                                              
            FROM data_command
WHERE (data_command_item IN (".implode(",",$ArrMyNumbers).")) "
```

Now you can approach in different ways to combine the data from the first set with the second.

Assuming you can represent the resultset in PHP, I advice you to store the whole resultset in an array, using a key, being "number" in this case. Make sure it is unique!
Also, just add to your first query a field named "price", and make it always -1 to indicate that is isn't set yet. (This is only for yourself, so you can easily see you haven't found a price in the second database.)

eg:

```
    $sql = "
            SELECT 
            left(list_product_order.number,8) as number,
            -1 as price,
            list_product_order.created_at as date,
```

Next, use something like this:

```
$firstRS = array();
foreach ($data_req as $one){
   $firstRS[$one["number"]] = $one;
}
```

Now you have your resultset mapped, with "number" being the index.
This makes it easy to find the right row.

Now to the second query, once you ran it, you simply loop over the resultset, pick up both "number" and "price", and use them to update the first resultset (named $firstRS here by me)

Something like:

```
foreach ($RS_Second as $one){
   $firstRS[$one["number"]]["price"] = $one["price"];
}
```

Now you have  $firstRS to work with, including updated prices from the second query.

Please note that this is a general approach that works across different databases. When you are working with the same database-vendor, it might be easier to simply use the (more complicated) join syntax ACROSS databases.
Just look it up on google for your database (use words like cross join across database X, where X is your database)

Comment: i know in php i can cross two different databases with foreach but i don't how

Comment: Yeah i have the same numbers of field number in my second data i want to use this field  to return a price which i can found it in my second database.

Comment: I'll make an addition

Comment: In my original answer. Read it again please.

Comment: I modify my code with ur code can u check my question?

Comment: I can't use join my databases they are not in the same server.

Comment: What about specifying it  in the where clause? where db.field1 = db2.field1

Comment: @Sarah I don't know want to do your project. I gave you a clear conceptual solution, it is up to you to implement it. Try it in steps: first make sure your can fill an array with the right values for "number" from the first query: output the array with print_r() or so. Second, try to use these numbers in your second query. If that succeeds (inspect your results!), try to combine the results of the second with the first.

Comment: @ErwinMoller i didn't demand u to do my project, i do it myself. I ask u just for my code if i really undertand what u wrote it for me.Anyway, Thank u for ur answers.

Comment: You didn't implement my code because you didn't use the numbers produced in the first query in your second. (In my code: where I use implode). I cannot really read your code either. There are mistakes in it (like a rouge <?php endforeach; ?>), so I am willing to help, but cannot based on what you posted.

Comment: @ErwinMoller Thank u. I will modify my code to be clear.

Comment: @Sarah How urgent is this? i can only work on this later today.

Comment: @Sarah I still see a strange endforeach. ANyway, make sure you execute your first query only once, then use it's "numbers" to create the second query, using implode as in my example, to find the right rows. As far as I can tell both queries should only run once. Then why do I still see your  <?php endforeach; ?>? Also inspect your $firstRS simply by using print_r() with <pre> and </pre> wrapped around. What is in it? Is the price column filled now?

Comment: @ReaganGallant I really want to do it as soon as possible. No problem,thank u for ur interest

Comment: @ErwinMoller I am trying to test the code I'll edit my question. Thanks a lot for ur interest.